# Как прервать выполнение программы Python?

Tags: python

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться. Запускаю данную программу, ничего не происходит. Когда выключаю ее, PyCharm пишет , line 6, in 
while sk < 400:
^^^^^^^^
KeyboardInterrupt

```
sk = 0
k = 1
kk = 2
kkk = 3
kkkk = 5
while sk < 400:
    k = kkk + kkkk
    if k + sk < 400:
        sk += k
    else:
        pass
    kk = kkkk + k
    if kk + sk < 400:
        sk += kk
    else:
        pass
    kkk = k + kk
    if kkk + sk < 400:
        sk += kkk
    else:
        pass
    kkkk = kk + kkk
    if kkkk + sk < 400:
        sk += kkkk
    else:
        pass
else:
    pass

print(sk)
```

Comment: Вы не "выключаете" её, а прерываете выполнение, поэтому и пишет ошибку.

Comment: Прочитайте подробнее про [KeyboardInterrupt](https://pythonz.net/references/named/keyboardinterrupt/)

Comment: Я ее прерываю по причине того, что такая программа не может работать более 1 минуты

Comment: Что тут происходит?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ничего не происходит - это не совсем верное определение поведения кода.
В вашем случае, - бесконечно повторяется выполнение тела цикла.

Переменная sk в результате первой итерации равна 76, в результате второй - 364, далее - изменение переменной не происходит. Соответственно - ваш цикл выполняется бесконечно. До команды

```
print(sk)
```

Вы не дойдете никогда. Из-за этого кажется, что "код ничего не делает".

А в целом - код стоит переписать по ряду причин:
Именование переменных не несет никакой информации, из-за этого тяжело разбирать код. Также ваши конструкции вида:

```
else: 
    pass
```

Не несут никакой смысловой нагрузки, поэтому их лучше безвозвратно удалить.

Также - прерывание выполнения кода посредством остановки в PyCharm не провоцирует выполнения последующих команд, это не завершение работы цикла.

Завершить цикл с последующим выполнением кода после него можно при помощи метода "break". Пример работы:

```
cycle_counter = 0  # инициализируем переменную, будем считать ее счетчиком циклов
while True:  # входим в бесконечный цикл
    if cycle_counter >= 2:
        break  # выходим из цикла
    cycle_counter += 1  # инкрементируем (увеличиваем на 1) переменную
print("Я нахожусь после цикла")
```

Comment: Можно вместо `pass` поставить `break` и работа кода прекратится )

Comment: @CrazyElf Тут не совсем ясно, какого эффекта хочет добиться автор, поэтому - не факт, что это решит его проблему)

Comment: Большее спасибо, вы мне очень помогли